# Metric inequality in Hilbert cube.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $x,y \in H^{\infty}$
(The Hilbert cube is the collection of all real sequences $x=(x_n$) with $|x_n|\leq 1)$
and $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $M_k= \max \{|x_1-y_1|,...,|x_k-y_k|\}$

And let:  $d(x,y)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |x_n-y_n|$

Show:

$$2^{-k} M_k \leq d(x,y) \leq M_k + 2^{-k+1}$$

---

I have only succeeded in proving that $2^{-k}M_k\leq 1$ but further than that I am struggling. Any hints?

(Sorry to the ones that tried to solve $d(x,y) \leq M_k + 2^{-k}$, I was just informed that there is a typo in the book.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |x_n - y_n| = \sum_{n=1}^k 2^{-n} |x_n - y_n| +\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty 2^{-n} |x_n - y_n| .$$

Comment: I already saw this but I am not sure how to use it in a constructive way. Could you explain to me please how to use this?

Comment: For the first sum, use $|x_n - y_n| \le M_k$.  For the second sum, use $|x_n - y_n| \le 1$.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you only know $|x_n - y_n| \le 2$.  So this doesn't quite give your result.  It gives $M_k + 2^{1-k}$.

Comment: And if you choose $x$ so that $x_n = 0$ for $1 \le n \le k$, and $x_n = 1$ otherwise, and set $y = -x$, then this shows that you cannot get the result you want.

Comment: I think the definition of the Hilbert cube is wrong. For me it was always $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$, i.e. $0 \le |x_n| \le 1$

Comment: In "Real Analysis" by N.L.Carothers , page 39 it states: "The Hilbert cube $H^{\infty}$ is the collection of all real sequences $x=(x_n)$ with $|x_n| \leq 1$ for $n= 1,2,...$"

Answer (score 1):

I will complement the other answer with a hint to the first inequality:

$$\forall m \in \mathbb N: \sum_{n \mathop= 1}^\infty 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|\ge2^{-m}|x_m-y_m|$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: M_k is one of the $|x_m - y_m|$, where $1 \le m \le k$. For these $m$, we also have $2^{-m}\ge 2^{-k}$.